# go get gopkg.in: Connection refused

Tags: git, go

I tried to install different packages from gopkg.in but none of them work.

Example:

`$ go get -v gopkg.in/gomail.v2`

```
Fetching https://gopkg.in/gomail.v2?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://gopkg.in/gomail.v2?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "gopkg.in/gomail.v2": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"gopkg.in/gomail.v2", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://gopkg.in/gomail.v2"} at https://gopkg.in/gomail.v2?go-get=1s
gopkg.in/gomail.v2 (download)
# cd .; git clone https://gopkg.in/gomail.v2 /data/gowork/src/gopkg.in/gomail.v2
Cloning into '/data/gowork/src/gopkg.in/gomail.v2'...
fatal: unable to connect to gopkg.in:
gopkg.in[0: 45.33.37.13]: errno=Connection refused

package gopkg.in/gomail.v2: exit status 128
```

My git version is 2.13.0 and I enabled git sslCertify with

```
$ git config --global http.sslVerify true
```

No firewall or proxy is blocking the connection to the SSL port on gopkg.in:

`$ nmap gopkg.in -p 443`

```
Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-10-13 12:54 CEST
Nmap scan report for gopkg.in (45.33.37.13)
Host is up (0.25s latency).
rDNS record for 45.33.37.13: 13.37.33.45.in-addr.arpa
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.53 seconds
```

Any clue?

Comment: Try to `curl -v https://gopkg.in/gomail.v2?go-get=1` and show errors.

Comment: This looks like a `git` issue. Can run the clone separately: `git clone https://gopkg.in/gomail.v2 /data/gowork/src/gopkg.in/gomail.v2`? If that fails, maybe see if the git trace output has any info with `GIT_TRACE=true`?

Comment: curl works without issues. The git clone fails. Also when I add git tracing no additional information is given: 
` 17:33:31.046341 git.c:369               trace: built-in: git 'clone' 'https://gopkg.in/gomail.v2' '/data/gowork/src/gopkg.in/gomail.v2'
Cloning into '/data/gowork/src/gopkg.in/gomail.v2'...
fatal: unable to connect to gopkg.in:
gopkg.in[0: 45.33.37.13]: errno=Connection refused `